# XSL Group by Item Model

Tags: xml, xslt

My problem is that I want to group by model for each item but I only want to load the details of single entity

```
<Search-Request search-term="1 tb">
    <Items>
        <Item href="SEA1TBST31000524AS.jpg" model="ST31000524AS">
            <Name>Seagate Hard disk 1TB ST31000524AS 3.5"</Name>
            <Price>60.50</Price>
            <SupplierCode>TECSEA1TB</SupplierCode>
            <Supplier>TEC001</Supplier>
            <Manufacturer>Seagate</Manufacturer>
            <CustomerReviews>
                <Review>
                    <Reviewer>Hayley Park</Reviewer>
                    <Rating>5</Rating>
                    <Review>I bought this because my boyfriend suggested it. But I am glad I did since it has a good amount of storage. And was quite cheap.</Review>
                </Review>
                <Review>
                    <Reviewer>Bill Gates</Reviewer>
                    <Rating>3</Rating>
                    <Review>Not that big storage wise but can't complain too much about price.</Review>
                </Review>
                <Review>
                    <Reviewer>Jean Pierre Said</Reviewer>
                    <Rating>4</Rating>
                    <Review>So far I've been using this product for a year and have no disregrets since it is much better than the previous hdd which I had which was only 256GB.</Review>
                </Review>
            </CustomerReviews>
        </Item>
        <Item href="" model="ST31000524AS">
            <Name>Seagate Hard disk 1TB ST31000524AS 3.5 inch</Name>
            <Price>55.50</Price>
            <SupplierCode>SCASEA1TB</SupplierCode>
            <Supplier>SCA001</Supplier>
            <Manufacturer>Seagate</Manufacturer>
            <CustomerReviews>
                <Review>
                    <Reviewer>Kyle Werner</Reviewer>
                    <Rating>4</Rating>
                    <Review>Very reliable product and at a great price.</Review>
                </Review>
                <Review>
                    <Reviewer>Scar Russo</Reviewer>
                    <Rating>5</Rating>
                    <Review>My only regret is that I didn't buy this after the price drop. Overall the product is great value for money.</Review>
                </Review>
                <Review>
                    <Reviewer>Stan Lee</Reviewer>
                    <Rating>1</Rating>
                    <Review>I don't know if it's me but this product burned out on me after just 2 weeks.</Review>
                </Review>
            </CustomerReviews>
        </Item>
     </Items>
```

So the above XML would contain the first element encountered

```
<Item href="SEA1TBST31000524AS.jpg" model="ST31000524AS">
         <Name>Seagate Hard disk 1TB ST31000524AS 3.5"</Name>
         <Manufacturer>Seagate</Manufacturer>  
</Item>
```

I would like to know if I could select both prices then select only the best price to display. The other prices could be listed in a tool-tip for example.

and review wise combine them

I know this isn't something simple.

I easily was able to list them with a for each on each item.

But I wanted it too look more refined but the requirement was that no high level language code be used so I ask you guys if this is possible.

Also if possible can items be split into multiple pages you know for example display 5 per page.Although this is not necessary it was just something esthetic which I wondered if it was possible.

Comment: This is a very simple task. The keywords you are looking for are "Muenchian grouping" and "`<xsl:key>`". There are literally hundreds upon hundreds of examples on StackOverflow alone. You need to specify how your output HTML should look like exactly (I don't think you've done that so far). Then please try to solve it yourself and post a code sample when you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find out how to do what I needed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Price">
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
<li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Search-Request">
<html>
<body>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Items/Item" group-by="@model">
        <xsl:sort select="@model" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="@model"/></p>
        <ol>
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/Price">
<xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
        </ol>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

now I just need to apply the rest of the elements and it will be complete.

Comment: +1 That's it. For your next XSLT question don't forget to mention that you're on XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Tomalak Well I wasn't aiming for xslt 2 but i found that the solution seemed simpler.

Comment: It is. Simpler than XSLT 1.0 would have been anyway. And it's exactly the correct way to solve this problem.